# TeleStax Restcomm integration in MetaSwitch Clearwater

Tags: sip, voip, telephony, mobicents, restcomm

We have tried to deploy RestComm server in our LAB, but have some troubles to integrate it to IMS.

At that moment we have:
6 virtual machine (Clearwater IMS: sprout, bono, ellis, homer, homestead; Telestax: restcomm) on one physical appliance in one network subnet.

We have tested Restcomm AMI Demos, all works good. Text-to-Speech works, calls are working.

Than we tried integrate Clearwater IMS and restcomm (http://telestax.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ClearWater-RestComm-Integration-2013.pdf), but here we have the non working solution:

```
  10.199.200.89 -> 10.199.200.95 SIP/SDP 399 Request: INVITE sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru, with session description
  10.199.200.95 -> 10.199.200.89 SIP 801 Status: 404 Not found
  10.199.200.89 -> 10.199.200.95 SIP 556 Request: ACK sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru
```

(10.199.200.89 - clearwater-sprout, 10.199.200.95 - restcomm, 0000006606 - sip sip number on restcomm)

restcomm responding "404 Not found”, as we understand  this happened because the domain is "cw.domain.ru", but have not found any config parameters to set. In the result we have not working call flow from Clearwater IMS to the Restcomm service.

In the Restcomm logs we have:

```
12:25:32,603 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12908) Invalidating the following sip application session 671d0ad7-baf1-4867-b
4c1-a1d572e3a37c;RestComm

12:25:32,604 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12908) Invalidating the sip session (97067297_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_671d0ad7-baf1-4867-b4c1-a
1d572e3a37c;e2c424771fe1c2d0d8a88873fd103485@10.199.200.95;671d0ad7-baf1-4867-b4c1-a1d572e3a37c;RestComm)

12:25:32,604 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12908) The following sip application session 671d0ad7-baf1-4867-b4c1-a1d572e3a
37c;RestComm has been invalidated

12:26:30,998 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (SIP-TCP-Core-PipelineThreadpool-7) <message
from="10.199.200.89:51730" 
to="10.199.200.95:5080" 
time="1429521990997"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkpjyfeolh7nut46itlpj376kiq3nchyw7ga" 
callId="1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC" 
firstLine="INVITE sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[INVITE sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.89:51730;rport=51730;branch=z9hG4bKPjyfeOlh7NUt46itlpj376kIQ3ncHyW7ga;received=10.199.200.89
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.87:42302;rport=42302;received=10.199.200.87;branch=z9hG4bKPjjmliVkif1UEiatjnn-ja0uL8bw3zF7RD
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.30.122:5062;rport=50235;received=10.199.30.122;branch=z9hG4bK2054587840;alias
Record-Route: <sip:sprout.cw.domain.ru:5054;transport=TCP;lr;service=scscf;billing-role=charge-orig>
Record-Route: <sip:10.199.200.87:5058;transport=TCP;lr>
Record-Route: <sip:Ws8ywGuzBs@bono01.cw.domain.ru:5060;transport=TCP;lr>
From: "0000006625@cw.domain.ru" <sip:0000006625@cw.domain.ru>;tag=71152997
To: <sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru>
Call-ID: 1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC
CSeq: 10 INVITE
Contact: "0000006625@cw.domain.ru" <sip:0000006625@10.199.30.122:5062;transport=tcp>
Max-Forwards: 64
User-Agent: Grandstream GXP1405 1.0.7.4
Supported: replaces,path,timer
Allow: INVITE,ACK,OPTIONS,CANCEL,BYE,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,REFER,UPDATE,MESSAGE
Accept: application/sdp,application/dtmf-relay
P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:0000006625@cw.domain.ru>
Session-Expires: 600
Privacy: none
Route: <sip:10.199.200.95:5080;lr>
Route: <sip:odi_vzCEsiz4y5@10.199.200.89:5054;lr>
P-Served-User: <sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru>;regstate=reg;sescase=term
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 410
v=0
o=0000006625 8001 8000 IN IP4 10.199.30.122
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 10.199.30.122
t=0 0
m=audio 5008 RTP/AVP 0 8 18 97 9 4 2 101
a=sendrecv
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=ptime:20
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
a=rtpmap:97 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:97 mode=30
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:4 G723/8000
a=rtpmap:2 G726-32/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
]]>
</message>

12:26:31,006 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12910) <message
from="10.199.200.95:5080" 
to="10.199.200.89:51730" 
time="1429521991006"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkpjyfeolh7nut46itlpj376kiq3nchyw7ga" 
callId="1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 404 Not found" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 404 Not found
To: <sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru>;tag=57299471_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_a01b3174-c173-4651-8c15-8b5cf0ecbfd9
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.89:51730;rport=51730;branch=z9hG4bKPjyfeOlh7NUt46itlpj376kIQ3ncHyW7ga;received=10.199.200.89
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.87:42302;rport=42302;received=10.199.200.87;branch=z9hG4bKPjjmliVkif1UEiatjnn-ja0uL8bw3zF7RD
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.30.122:5062;rport=50235;received=10.199.30.122;branch=z9hG4bK2054587840;alias
CSeq: 10 INVITE
Call-ID: 1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC
From: "0000006625@cw.domain.ru" <sip:0000006625@cw.domain.ru>;tag=71152997
Server: Mobicents Restcomm MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER.BUILD_NUMBER
Contact: <sip:10.199.200.95:5080;transport=tcp>
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</message>

12:26:31,007 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.dispatchers.InitialRequestDispatcher] (SIP-TCP-Core-PipelineThreadpool-7) Request event dispatched to RestComm

12:26:31,012 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (SIP-TCP-Core-PipelineThreadpool-8) <message
from="10.199.200.89:51730" 
to="10.199.200.95:5080" 
time="1429521991011"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkpjyfeolh7nut46itlpj376kiq3nchyw7ga" 
callId="1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC" 
firstLine="ACK sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[ACK sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.89:51730;rport=51730;branch=z9hG4bKPjyfeOlh7NUt46itlpj376kIQ3ncHyW7ga;received=10.199.200.89
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "0000006625@cw.domain.ru" <sip:0000006625@cw.domain.ru>;tag=71152997
To: <sip:0000006606@cw.domain.ru>;tag=57299471_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_a01b3174-c173-4651-8c15-8b5cf0ecbfd9
Call-ID: 1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC
CSeq: 10 ACK
Route: <sip:10.199.200.95:5080;lr>
Route: <sip:odi_vzCEsiz4y5@10.199.200.89:5054;lr>
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</message>

12:26:32,645 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12910) <message
from="10.199.200.95:5080" 
to="10.199.30.107:43240" 
time="1429521992644"
isSender="true" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4_57a5b08a_d9ab1446-96ab-402f-b751-cd728cb74353" 
callId="5a0703819a997212235257c2ebf3741f@10.199.200.95" 
firstLine="OPTIONS sip:bob@10.199.30.107:43240;transport=tcp;lr SIP/2.0" 
>
<![CDATA[OPTIONS sip:bob@10.199.30.107:43240;transport=tcp;lr SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 5a0703819a997212235257c2ebf3741f@10.199.200.95
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
From: <sip:restcomm@10.199.200.95>;tag=94331963_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4
To: <sip:bob@10.199.30.107:43240>
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: Mobicents Restcomm MAJOR_VERSION_NUMBER.BUILD_NUMBER
Contact: <sip:restcomm@10.199.200.95:5080;transport=tcp>
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.95:5080;branch=z9hG4bK79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4_57a5b08a_d9ab1446-96ab-402f-b751-cd728cb74353
Route: <sip:bob@10.199.30.107:43240;transport=tcp;lr>
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</message>

12:26:32,692 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (SIP-TCP-Core-PipelineThreadpool-9) <message
from="10.199.30.107:43240" 
to="10.199.200.95:5080" 
time="1429521992692"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bk79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4_57a5b08a_d9ab1446-96ab-402f-b751-cd728cb74353" 
callId="5a0703819a997212235257c2ebf3741f@10.199.200.95" 
firstLine="SIP/2.0 200 OK" 
>
<![CDATA[SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 10.199.200.95:5080;branch=z9hG4bK79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4_57a5b08a_d9ab1446-96ab-402f-b751-cd728cb74353
From: <sip:restcomm@10.199.200.95>;tag=94331963_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4
To: <sip:bob@10.199.30.107:43240>;tag=995341531
Call-ID: 5a0703819a997212235257c2ebf3741f@10.199.200.95
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Supported: replaces,path,timer
User-Agent: Grandstream GXP1405 1.0.7.8
Allow: INVITE,ACK,OPTIONS,CANCEL,BYE,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,REFER,UPDATE,MESSAGE
Content-Length: 0
]]>
</message>

12:26:32,696 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12910) Invalidating the following sip application session 79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4;RestComm

12:26:32,696 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12910) Invalidating the sip session (94331963_ba1d553a_57a5b08a_79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4;5a0703819a997212235257c2ebf3741f@10.199.200.95;79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4;RestComm)

12:26:32,697 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (RestComm-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-12910) The following sip application session 79f90da6-eedd-48e9-9298-0de946eb7ac4;RestComm has been invalidated

12:26:39,510 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipSessionImpl] (MSS-Executor-Thread-3) Invalidating the sip session (71152997;1025744989-5062-2@BA.BJJ.DA.BCC;a01b3174-c173-4651-8c15-8b5cf0ecbfd9;RestComm)

12:26:39,511 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (MSS-Executor-Thread-3) Invalidating the following sip application session a01b3174-c173-4651-8c15-8b5cf0ecbfd9;RestComm

12:26:39,511 INFO  [org.mobicents.servlet.sip.core.session.SipApplicationSessionImpl] (MSS-Executor-Thread-3) The following sip application session a01b3174-c173-4651-8c15-8b5cf0ecbfd9;RestComm has been invalidated

12:27:12,016 INFO  [gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPTransactionStack] (SIP-TCP-Core-PipelineThreadpool-10) <message
from="10.199.200.89:34239" 
to="10.199.200.95:5080" 
time="1429522032014"
isSender="false" 
transactionId="z9hg4bkpjvmnmgxo253hvm75so5qm.sn-vccrqjfa" 
callId="231825113" 
firstLine="INVITE sip:0000006625@cw.domain.ru SIP/2.0"
```

---

1. RestComm version: mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2
2. 0000006606 was configured on restcomm:

```
    {  
    "sid": "PN9905e897237440aaad83af5ee9b8d502",  
    "account_sid": "ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf",  
    "friendly_name": "0000006606",  
    "phone_number": "0000006606",  
    "voice_url": "/restcomm-rvd/services/apps/rvdSayVerbDemo/controller",  
    "voice_method": "POST",  
    "voice_fallback_url": null,  
    "voice_fallback_method": "POST",  
    "status_callback": null,  
    "status_callback_method": "POST",  
    "voice_caller_id_lookup": false,  
    "voice_application_sid": null,  
    "date_created": "Mon, 20 Apr 2015 19:00:34 +0300",  
    "date_updated": "Mon, 20 Apr 2015 19:00:34 +0300",  
    "sms_url": null,  
    "sms_method": "POST",  
    "sms_fallback_url": null,  
    "sms_fallback_method": "POST",  
    "sms_application_sid": null,  
    "capabilities": {  
    "voice_capable": false,  
    "sms_capable": false,  
    "mms_capable": false,  
    "fax_capable": false  
    },  
    "api_version": "2012-04-24",  
    "uri": "/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PN9905e897237440aaad83af5ee9b8d502.json"  
    }
```

3. I tried to call number 1234 using the softphone, registered on restcomm. And it's works.
4. Yes i've seen it http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-understanding-autoconfigure-script/ and net ports on restcomm:

```
@rcomm01:~$ netstat -nlptu  
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
 Active Internet connections (only servers)
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address           State       PID/Program name  
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      3049/java  
 tcp        0      0 10.199.200.95:8080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8787            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                 
 tcp        0      0 10.199.200.95:5080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 10.199.200.95:5081      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 10.199.200.95:5082      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 10.199.200.95:4447      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9990          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3049/java         
 tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                 
 udp        0      0 10.199.200.95:5080      0.0.0.0:*                           3049/java         
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48637           0.0.0.0:*                           -                 
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -                 
 udp        0      0 10.199.200.95:2427      0.0.0.0:*                           3050/java         
 udp        0      0 10.199.200.95:2727      0.0.0.0:*                           3049/java         
 udp6       0      0 :::39678                :::*                                -
```

Answer (score 2):

Which version of RestComm do you use ?
Did you configured 0000006606 to a RestComm application ? Did you try calling first to 1234 to see if you get the Media announcement played back as a smoke test ?
You can use the latest binary from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/view/RestComm/job/RestComm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/ to overcome the 404.
By the way http://telestax.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/ClearWater-RestComm-Integration-2013.pdf is a little bit out of date, please use http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-understanding-autoconfigure-script/, Section "Binding to a different IP address" to start RestComm. That way it will automatically modify the IP addresses in all configuration files.

Comment: Hello, i added additional information to main question.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version: mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.2.2.4.
And on this version, i do not get the message "SIP: Not Found".
But there is other problem, after the restcomm launch, the first call is proceeding normally (but not always). The following calls without sound, because restcomm not sending rtp packets. I attached network capture log, standalone log and mobicent media log to be able analyse this behaviour. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf039wu66ihp285/restcomm_logs.zip?dl=0
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @boboba checking the pcap file, I can see that the initial INVITE comes from ip address 10.199.200.89, which is a Grandstream sip device as I can see from the User-Agent header, but the SDP that offers asks for RTP connection at ip address "IN IP4 10.199.30.122" port 5008. This looks wrong to me and that seems to be the issue that causes no announcements.

Comment: @GeorgeVagenas As I understand, it is not a problem, the RFC (ietf.org/rfc/rfc2327.txt) says that "is the globally unique address of the machine from which the session was created " ("Origine" section) and "unicast IP address of the expected data source or data relay or data sink as determined by additional attribute fields." ("Connection Data" section). Flow scheme: projectclearwater.org/technical/call-flows , where AS == restcomm, and again first call works

Comment: @boboba, agree, since this is a sip device I was expecting that the RTP connection would be with the sip device, I thought you had the wrong ip address at the c line by mistake. 
The pcap file you sent doesn't have the MGCP requests and responses, please take a new capture, different pcap for every call and make clear which pcap is for the failed call, but this time use "any" for the interface, such as: "tcpdump -i any -w YOUR_FILE.pcap"

Comment: @GeorgeVagenas, new logs: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4smxxpqc0as094/restcomm_logs01.zip?dl=0  Additionaly, i have attached clearwater logs(sprout, bono), maybe it would be helpful.

Comment: @jeand Hello, the problem is still relevant for me. I test new versions of restcomm from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/view/RestComm/job/RestComm/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/, but issue is not solved, yet. It would be good, if you told me what logs will be helpful for you to solve this problem. I will collect it, and we can try to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you retry with the latest release http://www.telestax.com/restcomm-7-3-0-is-here/ ?

Comment: @jeand hello, sorry for delay. All the same on  https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/issues?q=milestone%3A7.3.0+is%3Aclosed. i get no sound. What type of logs need to provide to solve the problem?

Comment: @boboba, from the last pcap file you sent, I can see that Restcomm sends some RTP traffic to the proper ip address/port (as described in the c line of the SDP in the INVITE).
Please use the latest Restcomm 7.3.0.GA to make one more test call and capture the pcap,

Comment: @boboba, also please edit the following file : $RESTCOMM_HOME/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-media-server.sh and change the property "useSbc" to false (https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm/blob/master/release/config-scripts/as7-config-scripts/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-media-server.sh#L13). Then restart Restcomm and make one more test call and capture the trace in a new pcap file.

Comment: @jeand hello, all logs here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9i0xy6659a0kalr/restcomm_logs_8062015.zip?dl=0 , restcomm version: Mobicents-Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.3.0.641